# What PolyFuse should I have to protect 150 Ohms 0.5W resistor?

Tags: resistors, circuit-protection, polyfuse

I need help selecting a polyfuse for protecting a 150 Ohms 0.5W resistor.

My goals are:

- To make sure that the resistor won't take any damage when I apply voltage over 3V onto the 150 Ohm resistor
- I must be possible apply 3V or below onto the 150 Ohm resistor, without the PolyFuse should "wake up" and turn down the current by increasing the resistanse.

What do you think I should select? **A** or **B**?
I want to select **A** but the problem is that if I apply 20mA, it will take 100 seconds for the polyfuse to "wake up" and break down the current. 20mA over 150 Ohm resistor is 3V. So I don't know what to select. Do you have any suggestions?

[image]

http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2830168.pdf?_ga=2.213747988.1004593585.1603574478-32033874.1602687410

Comment: A 150 ohm resistor can handle more than 8 volts before it dissipates 0.5 W. Why are you protecting it from 3 volts? In practice, it would handle 1 watt (or over 12 volts) for a short time. If you describe the problem you are trying to solve, we could come up with a solution.

Comment: @Barry I want to measure 4-20mA with a MCU ADC and that ADC measure voltage. To convert 4-20mA signal to voltage (0.7v-3.0v) by using 150 Ohm resistor, I need also protecting it from voltage above 3v e.g 5 or 6. I don't know. Let's say 5 voltage as the maximum limit for the 150 Ohm resistor? Then I want the PolyFuse to "wake up" and break down the current.

Comment: You should be more worried about protecting the MCU, not the resistor. If so then edit the question to reflect what you really want to protect.

Comment: @Justme I have a 2k resistor and a schottky diode before the MCU. MCU is well protected from high voltage.